# Raw SOAP Magento Requests

Tags: web-services, magento, soap

Im trying to find information on how to post data to Magento 1.9 SOAP API using PAW / POSTMAN.

Most importantly Im trying to find out how to add filters into the requests

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<urn:salesOrderList soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">alreadydefinedandworking</sessionId>
</urn:salesOrderList>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Im currently using Soap UI to do my tasks but im stuck on how to add filters into the SOAP packets so I can get data out of Magento.

Is there any location online with Gists for the basics on connecting to Magento using the XML packets? Or if anyone knows how to add the filter in for incremental_id that would be super nice of you

Answer (score 0):

request nodes differ depending on what type of soap API you use in Magento.

There are:

- Soap v1
- Soap v2
- WS-I

if you use the most compatible WSI mode - request param definition looks like this:

```
<xsd:element name="salesOrderListRequestParam">
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="filters" type="typens:filters"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

where filters ns is:

```
<xsd:complexType name="filters">
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="filter" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xsd:element name="complex_filter" type="typens:complexFilterArray" minOccurs="0"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

both values are array-objects with key value pairs.

For more info see the code in API Helper, method: parseFilters() and _parseComplexFilter if you use conditions in filter.

**some example (Soap_v2):**

```
<ns1:salesOrderListRequestParam>
<sessionId>your sesion id</sessionId>
    <filters>
        <filter>
            <complexObjectArray>
                <key>increment_id</key>
                <value>12345</value>
            </complexObjectArray>
        </filter>
    </filters>
</ns1:salesOrderListRequestParam>
```